# Confirmation Email in aspnetboilerplate

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, email-confirmation

How can i send confirmation email and validate the confirmation in aspnetboilerplate template

```
CheckErrors(await _userManager.CreateAsync(user));
var emailConfirmationToken = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
```

email confirmation token is generated and sending in mail but how can i store it in database to confirm the email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply assign it to `user`:

```cs
CheckErrors(await _userManager.CreateAsync(user));
await CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

var emailConfirmationToken = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
user.EmailConfirmationCode = emailConfirmationToken; // Here
```